# How do I combine different kind of missing_values in sklearn's SimpleImputer into one

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have data with two different kind of missing values (np.nan and None) and I am trying to impute them using SimpleImputer.
Though I am able to do this in two steps I was wondering if there is a way to combine it into one.
My code is below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

train = pd.DataFrame({
        'users':[None,'John Johnson',np.nan,'John Smith','Mary Williams','ted bundy'],
})
test = pd.DataFrame({
        'users':[None,np.nan,'John Smith','Mary Williams','Andy Rollins'],
})

si1 = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='NAN')
si2 = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',missing_values = None, fill_value='MISSING')
train_imputed_interim1 = si1.fit_transform(train)
train_imputed = si2.fit_transform(train_imputed_interim1)
test_imputed_interim1 = si1.fit_transform(test)
test_imputed = si2.fit_transform(test_imputed_interim1)
print('\ntrain_imputed:')
print(train_imputed)
print('\ntest_imputed:')
print(test_imputed)
```

Is there a way to combine si1 and si2 into one. I tried

```py
si = SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',missing_values = [None,np.nan], fill_value='MISSING')
```

but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the None and np.nan values with 'MISSING' you can use pd.DataFrame.replace().

```
test.replace(np.nan, "MISSING") 

           users
0        MISSING
1        MISSING
2     John Smith
3  Mary Williams
4   Andy Rollins
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this strictly speaking with one `SingleImputer`.

One option, like mentioned in the previous answer, is to use pandas' `replace`, but if you want to stick to the scikit-learn toolkit, you could be using a `Pipeline` instead, which arguably is a little more elegant than the two-steps solution you already have:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipe = Pipeline([('si1',SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',fill_value='NAN')),
                ('si2', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant',missing_values = None, fill_value='MISSING'))])
print('\ntrain_imputed:')
print(pipe.fit_transform(train))
print('\ntest_imputed:')
print(pipe.transform(test))
```

This will give you the same results.